# .Net Core Filters in a Gateway API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'd like to incorporate filters into a Gateway API project that I've created.  There are no controllers in this project (I think this is important to note). It fronts a number microservices, serves as a reverse proxy, and performs cross-cutting concerns as well as orchestration.  I need to apply various filters to requests in the pipeline - mostly to include header data.  I've not been able to apply the filters - breakpoints don't get hit and no exceptions.

I have 3 questions:

- How do I get the filters to work?
- How can I pass arguments to filters at design time?
- How can I pass an argument to filters at runtime (dependencies)?  See the code sample last line

**STARTUP.CS**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("app-cors-policy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition") //headers to be exposed
                        ;
                    });
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new ContentDispositionFilter(?????));
            });
        }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {           
        app.UseCors("app-cors-policy").UseMvc();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            _router.Request = context.Request;
            var httpResponseMessage = await _router.RouteRequest();

            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
//
// *** HOW DO I PASS httpResponseMessage TO A FILTER *** ???
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do both simultaneously. It's not clear if that's actually your requirement, but if so, you're out of luck.

To pass things in a design time, you literally use the constructor like any other class:

```
options.Filters.Add(new ContentDispositionFilter("foo"));
```

Which would then correspond to a constructor on that class like:

```
public ContentDispositionFilter(string myParam)
```

To add runtime dependencies, you'd have to utilize dependency injection. Simply, you make the constructor have params for the various dependencies:

```
public ContentDispositionFilter(Dependency1 dep1, Dependency2, dep2)
```

Then, to register the global filter, you'll have to do it by *type*, not reference. The way you're doing it currently is by reference, where your new it up in line. Instead, you'll need to do:

```
options.Filters.Add(typeof(ContentDispositionFilter));
```

And then, of course, you'll need to ensure that your filter is actually registered in the service collection:

```
services.AddScoped<ContentDispositionFilter>();
```

**EDIT**

It's worth mentioning that the service registration itself kind of gives you an opportunity to do both. You can actually pass a factory lambda to that like so:

```
services.AddScoped(p =>
{
    var dep1 = p.GetRequiredService<Dependency1>();
    return new ContentDispositionFilter("foo", dep1);
}
```

So here, you have some static thing (the string) you're passing in *and* getting a runtime service. The `p` param there is an instance of `IServiceProvider`, so you can retrieve any service you like from that.

**EDIT #2**

So, I just noticed the comment at the end of your code block:

```
//
// *** HOW DO I PASS httpResponseMessage TO A FILTER *** ???
//
```

Simply, you cannot. Not here. I'm not sure what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but this isn't the way to do it. This now seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Try creating a new question directly related to what you *actually* want, instead of the solution you *think* will get you there.

Comment: I'll try what you suggest.  One of my problems is that I can't get the code in the filters to hit breakpoints (OnResultExecuting/ed).  It's like it's not registered. Also, I don't need to this simultaneously.

Comment: Since I'm in an environment that doesn't use controllers, I'm thinking that filters are not the answer and maybe middleware is.  I mean, how can a filter react to an Action or Result if they don't exist in the pipeline.